# How to get this bonus 100 XP? NOT excellent throw!

Tags: pokemon-go

Not first time bonus, not using lucky egg.  It happened to me twice today.  Can anyone tell me how this can happen so I can try to do it to level up faster?

[image]

Comment: @Nic it means **dup**licat**e**.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know that but there wasn't an answer in that thread though

Comment: Just because the other thread doesn't have an answer, doesn't mean this isn't a dupe of that...

Comment: I just caught my 200th Pidgey and I got the bonus again.  So the "every 100th of the same pokemon caught gives you 100 XP bonus" theory could be true.